# Is there a `Split` equivalent to torch.nn.Sequential?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

A sample code for a `Sequential` block is

```
self._encoder = nn.Sequential(
        # 1, 28, 28
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, stride=3, padding=1),
        # 32, 10, 10 = 16, (1//3)(28 + 2 * 1 - 3) + 1, (1//3)(28 + 2*1 - 3) + 1
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
        # 32, 5, 5
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
        # 64, 3, 3
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=1),
        # 64, 2, 2
)
```

---

Is there some construct like `nn.Sequential` that puts modules in it **in parallel**?

I would like to now define something like

```
self._mean_logvar_layers = nn.Parallel(
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=0),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=0),
)
```

Whose output should be two pipes of data - one for each element in `self._mean_logvar_layers` which are then feedable to the rest of the network. Kind of like a multi-headed network.

---

My current implementation:

```
self._mean_layer = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=0)
self._logvar_layer = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=0)
```

and

```
def _encode(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]:
    for i, layer in enumerate(self._encoder):
        x = layer(x)

    mean_output = self._mean_layer(x)
    logvar_output = self._logvar_layer(x)

    return mean_output, logvar_output
```

I would like to treat the parallel construct as a layer.

Is that doable in PyTorch?

Comment: Parallel as in running in parallel (simultaneously) or just outputting two values but working sequentially? If it is the first case, what this parallelization would mean exactly (because you can do it pretty easily with some `.to` calls and different devices, see [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/model_parallel_tutorial.html)).

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I was meaning not to think about the backend technicalities. I want behavior similar to my current implementation, but to wrap it in a construct that would allow me to define "splits" in the network architecture. Preferably, running in parallel would be nice, but I have much less knowledge about GPU parallelism best practices, thus wanted to allow pytorch to do the magic for me.

Comment: There is no layer like this in PyTorch. Model parallelization is rarely done and usually does not bring up any/significant speed improvements, as it would be in this case most probably. You can code your own `Parallel` layer which will output multiple tensors,  but it would run sequentially (and is quite trivial, should I write it anyway?)

Comment: Simply use one layer followed by `torch.split`. See here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.split.html In this case you would use a conv with 128 out channels and split into two parts of size 64 each, along axis 1 (assuming channels_first data format). This is likely not a _general_ solution so I hesitate to post it as an answer, but it works well for most common cases like the VAE.

Comment: @xdurch0 you should post an answer for others anyway, it could be done generically, provided you create it as a class with choose'able `dim` on which this tensor should be split.

Comment: @xdurch0 I for one would like to see how that's done, if not for now, then for the future. I would also like to see how you would then use `.split` to feed into the decoder of the VAE (which I omitted for sake of simplicity). If you don't write an answer, then I will once I have made it work. Thanks :)

Comment: @xdurch0 Please notice that one layer isn't really a FC layer, but really 2X64 FC layers. How should I go about this?

Comment: @Gulzar Added an example of what `xdurch0` said. You could use that for fully connected layers also (although you have a convolutional layer here).

Comment: Thanks for adding it. I could also try writing an answer, but I'm not very familiar with pytorch -- I work with tensorflow, and there, that's what I would do. `tf.split` is nice in that it also allows you to simply specify the _number_ of splits (2, in this case) and will work out the output sizes. Looks like torch doesn't support this. As for Gulzars last comment: Actually, one size-128 FC layer is mathematically exactly the same as a concatenation of two size-64 layers that receive the same input (similar for convolution). That's why this is "okay" to do.

Comment: @xdurch0 actually I commented that this *isn't* the same. for example, chunk 1's neuron 32 shouldn't "see" chunk 2's neuron 20, while they do see each other in a 128 FC

Comment: @Gulzar you have `N` input and `M` outputs in your case twice (mean and variance). Each of those `M` see `N`. In case of `N->2M` each `M` also sees `N` inputs. It is exactly the same as @xdurch0 said, there is no connection between `M`s also. For FC think of it like multiclass logistic regression (without activation), each weight vector is independent of other weight vectors (same for convolution as pointed out).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Sequential split

What you can do is create a `Parallel` module (though I would name it differently as it implies this code actually runs in parallel, probably `Split` would be a good name) like this:

```
class Parallel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, *modules: torch.nn.Module):
        super().__init__()
        self.modules = modules

    def forward(self, inputs):
        return [module(inputs) for module in self.modules]
```

Now you can define it as you wanted:

```
self._mean_logvar_layers = Parallel(
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=0),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=0),
)
```

And use it like this:

```
mean, logvar = self._mean_logvar_layers(x)
```

### One layer and split

As suggested by [@xdurch0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9393102/xdurch0) we could use a single layer and split across channels instead, using this module:

```
class Split(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, module, parts: int, dim=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.parts
        self.dim = dim
        self.module = module

    def forward(self, inputs):
        output = self.module(inputs)
        chunk_size = output.shape[self.dim] // self.parts
        return torch.split(output, chunk_size, dim=self.dim)
```

This inside your neural network (notice `128` channels, those will be split into `2` parts, each of size `64`):

```
self._mean_logvar_layers = Split(
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=0),
    parts=2,
)
```

And use it like previously:

```
mean, logvar = self._mean_logvar_layers(x)
```

#### Why this approach?

Everything will be done in one swoop instead of sequentially, hence faster, but might be too wide if you don't have enough GPU memory.

### Can it work with Sequential?

Yes, it is still a layer. But next layer has to work with `tuple(torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor)` as inputs.

`Sequential` is also a layer, quite simple one, let's see `forward`:

```
def forward(self, inp):
    for module in self:
        inp = module(inp)
    return inp
```

It just passes output from previous model to the next and that's it.

Comment: Thanks! Can the `Split` module be fed into a `nn.Sequential` as if it were a layer?

Comment: @Gulzar See my edit, but why would you need it in this case?

Comment: All this is actually to be able to simplify my VAE to be able to contain the `mean` and the `logvar` in the encoder. I want it this way to be able to override an `_encoder` and a `_decoder` per dataset, but still use the same VAE wrapper code. I am testing my infrastructure on MNIST, but really working with unique data which is not suitable for debugging.

Comment: @Gulzar You can create a lot of different layers (like taking `tuple` as inputs and applying different `module`s on each item, similar to first `Parallel` in the answer above). It's Python all in all, so `list comprehensions` and related stuff will work and you can structure it any way you want (question though is it worth abstracting).

Comment: Is it worth abstracting is a good question. I wonder how one debugs their own code without an easy fallback to an easy dataset, or without very well defined unit tests. Any resource on this? Thanks for all the answers, I learned a lot today :)

Comment: @Gulzar I usually go for random inputs of specified shape to test the network implementation. When it comes to dataset, it depends how hard it is, but some validation of it's processing during the way helps. Nothing concrete or set in stone that I know of though.

Comment: What do you mean by "go for random inputs"? How do you see that it's working beside over fitting a single batch of random?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227652/discussion-between-szymon-maszke-and-gulzar).

Answer (score 0):

Following @Szymon Maszke's great answer(s), here is the full relevant code, after all augmentations:

```
class Split(torch.nn.Module):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65831101/is-there-a-parallel-equivalent-to-toech-nn-sequencial#65831101

    models a split in the network. works with convolutional models (not FC).
    specify out channels for the model to divide by n_parts.
    """
    def __init__(self, module, n_parts: int, dim=1):
        super().__init__()
        self._n_parts = n_parts
        self._dim = dim
        self._module = module

    def forward(self, inputs):
        output = self._module(inputs)
        chunk_size = output.shape[self._dim] // self._n_parts
        return torch.split(output, chunk_size, dim=self._dim)


class Unite(torch.nn.Module):
    """
    put this between two Splits to allow them to coexist in sequence.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(Unite, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, inputs):
        return torch.cat(inputs, dim=1)
```

And the usage:

```
class VAEConv(VAEBase):
    ...
    ...
    ...

    def __init__():
        ...
        ...
        ...
        self._encoder = nn.Sequential(
        # 1, 28, 28
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, stride=3, padding=1),
        # 32, 10, 10 = 16, (1//3)(28 + 2 * 1 - 3) + 1, (1//3)(28 + 2*1 - 3) + 1
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
        # 32, 5, 5
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
        # 64, 3, 3
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=1),
        Split(
                # notice out_channels are double of real desired out_channels
                nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=0),
                n_parts=2,
        ),
        Unite(),
        Split(
                nn.Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1),
                n_parts=2
        ),
    )

    def _encode(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]:
        for i, layer in enumerate(self._encoder):
            x = layer(x)

        mean_output, logvar_output = x
        return mean_output, logvar_output
```

This now allows to subclass the VAE and define a different encoder on **init** time.